# Bash - force error if variable not defined

Tags: bash

I work with a lot of shell scripts that use bash variables. So, for example, I might have a script like this:

```
option1="-blah_blah"
option2="-yada_yada"
option3="-whatever"
...
option99="-something_else"

./myCommand "$option1 $option12 $option97 $option45"
```

I am constantly editing that last command to run various engineering tests. The problem is, sometimes I misspell a variable. In that case, Bash simply substitutes an empty string, and my command does the wrong thing silently.

Is there a way to have Bash throw an exception when I try to use a variable that is not defined?

Comment: Not sure how this could possibly be a duplicate of that question, as it still would not prevent an error if I misspelled a variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

set -e # Stop on error. I can't believe that this is not default.

set -u # Stop if trying to use un-initialized variables.

Comment: `set -e` isn't as useful as you might like and can break in "interesting" ways so can't save you as much as you might want (and is sometimes actively not what you want). `set -u` is, likewise, somewhat annoying and not always as helpful as you would want (and sometime more exacting than you would like). Just for the record.

Comment: Read [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105), and you'll have a very good idea of why `set -e` is not default (beyond "making it default would break POSIX sh compatibility", which is reason enough).